# Sorting ques how to access the private vector values

Tags: c++, sorting

I am doing this problem on sorting which I think can be sorted either by Heap sort or Quick sort.

There is an array A of integers of size n which cannot directly be accessed. However, you can get true or false response to queries of the form A[i] < A[j].
It is given that A has only one duplicate pair, and rest all the elements are distinct. So it has n-1 distinct elements and 1 element which is same as one of the n-1 elements. Your task is to identify the indices of the two identical elements in A.

```
class hiddenVector {
        private:
             vector <int> data; // you cannot directly access this in your code since this is a private element
        public:
             int getSize();// it returns a non-negative integer equal to the size of the class member data.
             bool iLessThanj(int i, int j); // returns true if and only if data[i] is strictly less than data[j]

};
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with sorting?

Comment: @melpomene This a practice problem from the Sorting Section. So, I thought..  You may suggest some other way.

Comment: What do you mean, "other way"? What's the first way?

Comment: _a_ and _b_ are equals if `(a < b)` is false and `(b < a)` is false, look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is given that A has only one duplicate pair, and rest all the elements are distinct.  So it has n-1 distinct elements and 1 element which is same as one of the n-1 elements. Your task is to identify the indices of the two identical elements in A.

you do not need to access the elements, the indexes *a* and *b* are the solution when `iLessThanj(a, b)` returns false and `iLessThanj(b, a)` returns false too (of course with *b* != *a*)

so something like :

```
hiddenVector v;
... initialization of v
int n = v.getSize();

for (int a = 0; a < n; ++a) {
  int b;

  for (b = a+1; b < n; ++b) {
     if (!v.iLessThanj(a, b) && !v.iLessThanj(b, a)) {
       std::cout << "element is the same at indexes " << a << " and " << b << std::endl;
       break;
     }
  }
  if (b < n)
    break;
}
```

P.S. the complexity is O(n^2), look at the other answer, more complicated but with a lower complexity

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new vector which contains indexes of hidden vector, then sort it using public method `iLessThanj()` of hidden vector. Finally, look through sorted indexes to find a pair of equal elements, they are adjacent after sorting and `iLessThanj(i, i+1) == false` for them and only them.

This has O(nlogn) complexity in time and O(n) in memory.

```
hiddenVector a; // {1, 3, -2, -4, 3, 7} for example
// construct indexes array
std::vector<int> a_ind (a.getSize ());
for (int i = 0; i < a.getSize(); i++)
  a_ind[i] = i;

// now a_ind = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
// sort it
std::sort(begin(a_ind), end(a_ind),
      [&a] (int i, int j) { return a.iLessThanj(i, j); }
);
// now a_ind = {3, 2, 0, 1, 4, 5} 
// and it is equal to sequence of indexes in sorted hidden vector

// finally, compute an answer to your problem
std::pair<int, int> res = {};
for (int k = 0; k < a_ind.size()-1; k++) {
  int i = a_ind[k];
  int j = a_ind[k+1];
  if (!a.iLessThanj(i, j)) {
    res.first = i;
    res.second = j;
    break;
  }
}
// now res = {1, 4}
```

PS 
Speedtest results for discussion in comments (compiled & run with -O3):

```
N      squared_algo sublinear_algo
10     2.259e-07    1.1653e-06 
100    4.8259e-06   8.5859e-06 
1000   0.000218602  0.000118063 
10000  0.0138744    0.000718756 
100000 0.913739     0.00876182
```

Full speedtest coded is [here](https://pastebin.com/3xYmjPm5)

Comment: sorry but this is so complicated and expensive for nothing ;-)

Comment: @bruno It's faster than your solution.

Comment: @melpomene to create a new vector, then to sort it, then to iterate on it is faster ? really ? please explain...

Comment: @bruno You have two nested loops. That's O(n^2). Copying a vector is O(n), sorting it is O(n\*log n), iterating it again is O(n); total = O(n + n\*log n + n) = O(n\*log n).

Comment: Moreover, @Geeky 's data structure looks like as a good example to study std::sort.

Comment: The `&& !a.iLessThanj(j,i)` test is redundant. All distinct elements are strictly ascending in the sorted vector.

Comment: @melpomene I know the complexities, but you forget the time needed for each operation, from which size do you think that solution will be faster ? ;-)

Comment: let's find that size)

Comment: @bruno Always, apparently. I can't find a size where your solution is faster.

Comment: @melpomene, I've added speedtest results to the post, unsurprisingly It's faster after ~1000 elements.

Comment: @gimme_danger I thought it would be rather from 10000, the compiler/libs are better than I supposed, this is a good news of course ^^ Thank you for the time you used to do these tests. (BTW you are saying melpomene lied or is not able to do a serious test, ouch lol)

Comment: And that deserves UV, so I did ;-)

Comment: @bruno For smaller sizes my test code just output `0s` for each solution. I wasn't familiar enough with the `chrono` stuff to print very small durations. I also figured that for small vectors (= very quick answers) you don't much care about the algorithm.

Comment: @bruno, he was just ironic, for small N extra memory allocation, sorts etc have noticeable overhead.